# Missing source codes in kernel-devel on CentOS8

Tags: linux, centos, fuse

Installed kernel-devel with yum on CentOS, Why missing some source codes in some sub-directories (such as fs/fuse) ?

```
$ uname -r
4.18.0-348.el8.x86_64
$ ls /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64/fs/fuse/
Kconfig  Makefile
$ uname -r
4.18.0-348.el8.x86_64
$ ls /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-348.2.1.el8_5.x86_64/fs/fuse/
Kconfig  Makefile
```

It is expected as here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/v4.18/fs/fuse

```
Kconfig
Makefile
acl.c
control.c
cuse.c
dev.c
dir.c
file.c
fuse_i.h
inode.c
xattr.c
```

Comment: 'kernel-devel' is headers for building a kernel "module.ko" . The one header (fuse_i.h) is also *not* included in kernel-devel packages for other Linux OS.

Comment: Thank you, @Knud Larsen.  [posted and answered in Centos forum](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?f=54&t=78529)